# Flask with MongoDB using MongoKit to MongoLabs

Tags: heroku, flask, mlab, mongokit

I am a beginner and I have a simple application I have developed locally which uses mongodb with mongoKit as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

customerDB = MongoKit(app)
customerDB.register([CustomerModel])
```

then in views I just use the CustomerDB

I have put everything on heroku cloud but my database connection doesn't work.

I got the link I need to connect by:

```
heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI
```

but I am not sure how to pull this. I looked at the following post, but I am more confused
[How can I use the mongolab add-on to Heroku from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859532/how-can-i-use-the-mongolab-add-on-to-heroku-from-python)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-MongoKit/#configuration-values), Flask-MongoKit supports a set of configuration settings.

```
MONGODB_DATABASE
MONGODB_HOST
MONGODB_PORT
MONGODB_USERNAME
MONGODB_PASSWORD
```

The `MONGOLAB_URI` environment setting needs to be parsed to get each of these. We can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12040065/978961) to the question you linked to as a starting point.

```
import os
from urlparse import urlsplit

from flask import Flask
from flask_mongokit import MongoKit

app = Flask(__name__)

# Get the URL from the Heroku setting.
url = os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI', 'mongodb://localhost:27017/some_db_name')
# Parse it.
parsed - urlsplit(url)

# The database name comes from the path, minus the leading /.
app.config['MONGODB_DATABASE'] = parsed.path[1:]

if '@' in parsed.netloc:
    # If there are authentication details, split the network locality.
    auth, server = parsed.netloc.split('@')
    # The username and password are in the first part, separated by a :.
    app.config['MONGODB_USERNAME'], app.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'] = auth.split(':')
else:
    # Otherwise the whole thing is the host and port.
    server = parsed.netloc

# Split whatever version of netloc we have left to get the host and port.
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'], app.config['MONGODB_PORT'] = server.split(':')

customerDB = MongoKit(app)
```